# What means the href in <a href="?request=register"> Register</a>?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, href

I know the  HTML-attribute only as a normal link-attribute like this:

```
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

or like this:

```
    <a href="/bla/blabla/abc.html">abc</a>
```

But what means the href in

```
                 <a href="?request=register"> Register</a>
```

?
What is the name of this variant?

Comment: it means passing a parameter and value to same page

Comment: Sorry, i edited it correctly now....

Comment: It's a URL parameter (`$_GET["request"])` and appended to the current pages path.

Answer (score 0):

with this link
    Register
you call the same *.php site and transmit a GET-variable to this site.
The name of this variable is request and it's content is "register"